# Delete purchased application from the list

Tags: google-play-store, nexus-one, cyanogenmod

I've bought some application and I feel that I don't want to use it anymore and I've uninstalled it. However, when I opened `Downloads` tab in the Market, it is listed there even though it's not installed. So, how do I remove it from the list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you did not purchase the app (i.e. it was free), it should be gone.  If you did, then it's always there because you have purchased the right to download it.

Comment: Yeah, I know that, but how do I get rid of the app from the list (if it's possible)?

Comment: I do not think it's possible.  Beyond using a different Google account, but then you don't get your other paid apps.